# How to update a box

Tags: javascript, reactjs, refresh, page-refresh

How to update the following box...

```
<div className="container team-member-tasks">
      <header className="header-box">
        <h1>Team Member Tasks</h1>
```

...after marking a task as done as in the following script...

```
const TaskButton = task => {
          if (task.task.status !== 'Complete') {
            return (
              <td>
                <h3
                  onClick={() => markAsDone(task)}
                  style={{ color: 'red' }}
                  data-toggle="tooltip"
                  data-placement="top"
                  title="MARK AS DONE. MARKING THIS AS DONE WOULD REMOVE THE TASK PERMANENTLY."
                  className="markAsDoneButton"
                >
                  X
                </h3>
              </td>
            )
          } else {
            return <td></td>
          }
        }

        const markAsDone = async task => {
          task.task.status = 'Complete'
          const updatedTask = {
            taskName: task.task.taskName,
            priority: task.task.priority,
            resources: task.task.resources,
            isAssigned: task.task.isAssigned,
            status: task.task.status,
            hoursBest: parseFloat(task.task.hoursBest),
            hoursWorst: parseFloat(task.task.hoursWorst),
            hoursMost: parseFloat(task.task.hoursMost),
            estimatedHours: parseFloat(task.task.hoursEstimate),
            startedDatetime: task.task.startedDate,
            dueDatetime: task.task.dueDate,
            links: task.task.links,
            whyInfo: task.task.whyInfo,
            intentInfo: task.task.intentInfo,
            endstateInfo: task.task.endstateInfo,
            classification: task.task.classification,
          }
          await updateTask(String(task.task._id), updatedTask)
          await deleteSelectedTask(task.task._id, task.task.mother)
          await dispatch(getAllUserProfile())
          await fetchAllTasks()
        }
```

...using the corresponding state property, causing the page component  to be re-rendered with the new information?

If the delete task button is clicked, the task will be deleted from database.

Below are screenshots of the delete button.

[image]

But I need to auto refresh the box (or the whole page?) in the image if the delete button "X" is cliked

I'm tried...

1 - I set the initial state of the tasks in the page component (question: which page? The same where is the header-box? Shall I create a new jsx or can I use the same of the component? (maybe one of the mistakes)):

```
const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);
```

2 - I passed the tasks state as a prop to the TaskButton component (question: same script as taksButton? Shall I create a new jsx or can I use the same of the TaskButton  component?(maybe one of the mistakes)):

```
<TaskButton task={task} tasks={tasks} setTasks={setTasks} />
```

In the markAsDone function, I updated the tasks state and call the setTasks function to update the state:

```
const markAsDone = async task => {
  task.task.status = 'Complete';
  const updatedTask = { ... };
  await updateTask(String(task.task._id), updatedTask);
  await deleteSelectedTask(task.task._id, task.task.mother);
  await dispatch(getAllUserProfile());
  await fetchAllTasks();
  
  // Update task status
  const updatedTasks = tasks.map(t => {
    if (t._id === task.task._id) {
      return {
        ...t,
        status: 'Complete'
      };
    } else {
      return t;
    }
  });
  setTasks(updatedTasks);
};
```

In the page component, I used the updated tasks state to re-render the component (question: which page? The same where is the header-box? Shall I create a new jsx or can I use the same of the component? (maybe one of the mistakes)):

```
<div className="container team-member-tasks">
  <header className="header-box">
    <h1>Team Member Tasks</h1>
  </header>
  <TaskList tasks={tasks} />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given what you have provided, it seems that you are **looking for a way to update your UI upon the change of state of your tasks list** (`tasks`)

One method would be to use the `useState()` hook inside your `<TaskList tasks={tasks}/>` component to update the state and render the list according to your current tasks list.

A quick sketch of an example structure may look something like this (I have omitted the TaskButton component and your task data structure for simplicity):

**TaskList Component**

```
const TaskList = ({ tasks }) => {
  const [tasksState, setTaskState] = useState(tasks);

  const onRemove = (id) => {
    setTaskState(() => taskState.filter(t => t.id !== id));
    // other logic 
  }

   const onComplete = (id) => {
        const newTasks = tasksState.map(t => {
        if(t.id === id) {
          t.isComplete = !t.isComplete;
        }
        return t;
      });
      setTasks(() => newTasks);
   }
  return(
    <div>
      {tasksState.length !== 0 &&
         tasksState.map((t, idx) => {
            <TaskItem taskProps={t} onComplete={onComplete} onRemove={onRemove} />
         })
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

**TaskItem Component**

```
 const TaskItem = (props) => {

    // props.taskData is the shape of your data and is simply a placeholder
    const onComplete = () => {
      props.onComplete(props.taskData.id); 
    }

    const onRemove = () => {
     props.onRemove(props.taskData.id); 
    }

    return (
      <div> 
        {props.taskProps.taskData}
        <button onClick={onComplete}>Complete Me</button>
        <button onClick={onRemove}>Delete Me</button>
      </div>
    )

 }
```

In the above, we set up an initial state for your tasks list in the **TaskListComponent** which is the `tasks` prop we de structure. For the sake of this example, I am assuming the `tasks` prop is an array of objects.

We then set up methods to handle the removal and completion of a task which change the state of the current task list and thus re-render it. These methods take a task id to find the given element in the `tasksState` array.

When mapping the tasks to **TaskItems**, we provide component with onComplete and OnRemove props as pointers to the methods we have just made.

Then in the **TaskItem** component we create methods to handle the click of either button type and call the parent method (passing an id of the task to the parent for lookup). There are more succinct methods of doing this but I've kept it simple for this example.

Hope this helps.
Link to an example I made: [https://jsfiddle.net/danielheery20/ep2fcjxn/](https://jsfiddle.net/danielheery20/ep2fcjxn/22/)

*If there are any errors please mark this down or suggest changes. I could not ask clarifying questions as I do not have the rating to do so, that is why I am working on an assumption*